# fullcalendar javascript issue - its not showing the events in IE?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox, fullcalendar

On my team website: http://www.berzerkers.org, head over to the Schedule. The calendar is supposed to have a few events listed - it works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari - but not in IE...what is the issue? I don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you data is being generated from, there's an empty array element at the end of the events array:

```
events: [{id: 1, title: "BT Big Game", start: new Date(2009, 7, 8, 8), end: new Date(2009, 7, 8)},{id: 2, title: "Team Meeting @ Clubhouse", start: new Date(2009, 7, 2, 20), end: new Date(2009, 7, 2)},{id: 3, title: "Trip to Stingray", start: new Date(2009, 7, 7, 15), end: new Date(2009, 7, 7)},{id: 4, title: "Practice / Eazy's Going Away Party @ Cousins SI", start: new Date(2009, 7, 16, 8), end: new Date(2009, 7, 16)},{id: 5, title: "Berzerkers Team Tryouts at NYCPB", start: new Date(2009, 7, 11, 20), end: new Date(2009, 7, 11)},]
```

Notice the ,] at the end.

This is causing IE to throw an error when it tries to parse it.